# Windows 7 VPN for iPad

Tags: windows, vpn, ipad

Is it possible to set up a VPN server on my windows 7 machine so I can use VPN on my ipad from other networks?

Comment: From @Bilal Asif: There are two easy ways to set up VPN on IPad.To know more click on http://www.vpnranks.com/how-to-setup-vpn-on-ipad/

Answer (score 3):

You can setup a VPN server on windows 7:

Goto > Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections then >Change adapter settings.

**Then file > click New Incoming Connection.**

[image]

---

Add or select the users to access your computer.(disregard the _vmware user account)

[image]

---

How will people connect screen, check Through the Internet if this is only connection

[image]

---

Select type of network software and click Allow access

[image]

---

Finish

If you have issues, [here is a youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1s5JxMG06L4) from Derick Park

Port forward the VPN traffic for your broadband router/firewall (assuming your machine is behind one)

**On your IPAD:**

Tap Settings > General > Network > VPN > Add VPN Configuration. Then use the VPN settings for your device.

Comment: I tried that, but the ipad wasnt connecting properly to it (on a local connection selecting pptp) Says "A connection could not be established to the PPP Server." Firewall is not on.